# Prevent use of procmailrc by some users

Tags: postfix, procmail, spamassassin

We have an e-mail server running Postfix (SMTP) and Dovecot (POP/IMAP) on Debian 10. Users cannot log directly on it (SSH), but have access to their homes through NFS.

We would like to use Procmail to sort messages tagged as spam by SpamAssassin (`X-Spam-Flag: YES` header) in a separate folder for each user, using a global `/etc/procmailrc` file. This seems easy to do, as shown in https://serverfault.com/questions/488044/send-spam-mail-to-a-special-folder-using-postfix, to give an example.

The question is: we don't want to allow our users to use `$HOME/.procmailrc` files, for security reasons. Is there a way to prevent Procmail from activating `$HOME/.procmailrc` for most users, except for some trusted ones?

**EDIT**:

Considering tripleee's answer, I could then write a `/etc/procmailrc` file containing a test for privileged users (i.e. users allowed to have a local `.procmailrc` file) as this:

```
# /etc/procmailrc

# if the e-mail is flagged as spam, deliver it to $JUNK and stop
:0:
    * ^X-Spam-Flag: YES
    $JUNK

# if the user is NOT allowed to have a $HOME/.procmailrc,
# then deliver the message to the default mailbox and stop
:0W:
    # check whether the user is allowed to have a .procmailrc file
    * ! ? check_allowed_user $LOGNAME
    $DEFAULT

# else, do nothing (and $HOME/.procmailrc will be activated)
```

Do you think this is the way to go? If so, I just need to find a simple and robust way to make the `check_allowed_user` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to force Procmail to stop here and now is to simply deliver the message. Inside of `/etc/procmailrc` I guess you explicitly want to `DROPPRIVS` first.

```
DROPPRIVS=yes
:0:
$DEFAULT
```

Depending on what your local `DEFAULT` delivery action is set to, maybe remove the second colon to not attempt to lock the destination during delivery. If your mailboxes are traditional `/var/spool/mail/username` Mbox spools, those do require locking.

For the record, another way to force Procmail to terminate immediately is to assign a value to the special variable `HOST`. (If Procmail was invoked with multiple file name arguments and the current file is not the last one, it will still process any remaining files.)

There is also `DELIVERED=yes` which does not by itself stop Procmail from processing the rest of the current recipe file, but which in combination with `HOST=''` can be used to force Procmail to report a successful delivery to the caller.

Update: Your `check_allowed_user` script seems like a viable approach, though it might be more efficient if you could embed the check into `/etc/procmailrc` directly; if you have a fairly limited set of users, maybe something like

```
DROPPRIVS=yes
:0:
* ! LOGNAME ?? ^(arnie|bertie|cecilia)$
$DEFAULT
```

where `arnie`, `bertie`, and `cecilia` are your allowed users.

Running an external binary for every delivery is something you generally want to try to avoid, even though today's servers can probably handle it quite well (up to a point!)

Answer (score 0):

Procmail by itself does not have any provisions for that. You have to either modify procmail code by yourself and recompile, or craft some clever wrapper script around procmail that will do what you want.